# Comparing the same value across to datasets in R

Tags: r

I have to nearly identical files about customer information. I would like to validate one file against the other. Is there a good way in R that can pinpoint where 'status' is different across two files? I tried to merge the two files and change status in file 2 to status2, but ran into issues and then started wondering if there was a better way to go about this.
My data looks like this:

```
file 1                     file 2
CustomerID  Status                 CustomerID  Status
1709         low                      1709      low     
1803         high                     1803      low
1951         medium                   1951      medium
```

Comment: Merge by CustomerID seems the most sensible option to me. What issues did you run into?

Comment: `f12 <- merge(f1, f2, by = 'CustomerID'); f12$equal.status <- f12$Status.x == f12$Status.y`

Comment: Thank you! I the problem I had was that status from file 1 wasn't merging. I realized it was named slightly differently between files that for some reason must have been preventing it from coming over. It's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help everyone. There was a slight difference in the names of the status variables that seems to have caused one not to import on the merge. When I made the names identical, everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you named your files `file1` and `file2` and both are of equal length, you can do:

`unequal <- which(file1$Status != file2$Status)`

This will return the row index numbers. If you want to have the CustomerID, you can do:

`unequalCustomerID <- file1$CustomerID[unequal]`

Or of course in one statement:

`file1$CustomerID[which(file1$Status != file2$Status)]`

Answer (score 0):

If you read your files into dataframes, say df1 and df2.  You can try something like df1['status'] != df2['status']

```
df1 = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), status = c("low","low","high"))
df2 = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), status = c("high","low","high"))

df1['status'] != df2['status']

 status
[1,]   TRUE
[2,]  FALSE
[3,]  FALSE
```